# Gitlab cross-project artifact

Tags: maven, curl, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I have 2 separate gitlab projects, I've looked through the documentation for 2 days now but am still struggling to achieve what I'm trying for.

I have Project A, which generates the documentation for the whole project.

Project B is a Gitlab Pages project.

My `gitlab-ci.yml` file for Project A has a job like this

```
build_docs:
  stage: deploy
  artifacts:
    # Create Archive with name of [Current Job - Current Tag]
    name: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    paths:
      - documentation/build/dokka/
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble
    - ls $CI_PROJECT_DIR/documentation/build
    - echo "Job Name = $CI_JOB_NAME"
    - echo "Project Dir = $CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    - echo "Docs trigger key = $DOCS_TRIGGER_KEY"
    - echo "Test Unprotected Unmasked Trigger = $TEST_TRIGGER"
    - echo "Job Token = $CI_JOB_TOKEN"
    - echo "Job ID= $CI_JOB_ID"
    - echo "Triggering [Documentation Pipeline]; Artifact from ACL -> Documentation"
    - "curl -X POST -F token=${CI_JOB_TOKEN} -F ref=master https://gitlab.duethealth.com/api/v4/projects/538/trigger/pipeline"
```

This job triggers the following job in Project B:

```
get-artifacts:
  stage: get-artifacts
  script:
    - echo "I have been triggered!!"
    - echo "$CI_JOB_TOKEN"
    - echo "$CI_JOB_NAME"
    - echo "$CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    - ls $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    # List artifacts generated from acl project
    - 'curl --globoff --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: abc1234" "https://gitlab.duethealth.com/api/v4/projects/492/jobs"'
    # This should take artifacts from ACL and output them into --output filename
    - 'curl --location --output artifacts.zip --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.duethealth.com/api/v4/android-projects/492/jobs/63426/artifacts"'
    # - unzip build_docs-feature-inf-297-upload-kdoc-doc-mod-test.zip
    - ls $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - file $CI_PROJECT_DIR/artifacts.zip
    - ls
    only:
      variables:
        - $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"
  tags:
    - pages
```

Now, in the job logs of project A. The Artifacts are uploaded successfully and I see a size of ~50000

In the logs of project B, after 
`# List artifacts generated from acl project`
I DO see the zip file artifact

However it seems that my curl request to GET a jobs artifacts in incorrect somehow. If you look at the picture below you can see 2 things.

1.) The request size is much small than the upload. So we are uploading artifacts of size ~50000 but then we download those same artifacts at a size of ~1000

2.) The `zip` file the artifacts should be outputted is not a `zip` file even though it has the `.zip` file extension.

It seems to me like it is never actually fetching the artifacts and instead just creating some object named `artifacts.zip` which is not even a `zip` file and I'm assuming the file size I'm seeing is just the size of the empty `artifacts.zip`.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image: JobLog]

Comment: Add `curl --fail` to your command. Right now even if curl fails it will save result in artifacts.zip. You can check content of the file to see what really was returned from curl command `less artifacts.zip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with the URL, after using the correct URL the problem is fixed.